# Using sed to replace uppercase to lowercase, space to underscore then create a xml file with results

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, pipe

Apologies ahead of time if this is stated wrongly as I have searched but could not find how to `sed` + `echo` while using `while loop` to read a file.

I have a before.txt file that looks like this:

```
The sun is Shining
The moon is dull tonight
I Feel Like Dancing
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
<message>
        <source>the_sun_is_shinig</source>
        <translation>The sun is Shining</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>the_moon_is_dull_tonight</source>
        <translation>The moon is dull tonight</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>i_feel_like_dancing</source>
        <translation>I Feel Like Dancing</translation>
</message>
```

This is what I have so far ...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "" > json.xml
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/; s/ /_/g' < "$line" > temp.txt
   sourceline="$(cat temp.txt)"
   echo "<message>" >> json.xml
   echo -e "\t<source>${sourceline}<source>" >> json.xml
   echo -e "\t<translation>${line}<translation>" >> json.xml
   echo "<message>" >> json.xml
done < "$1"
rm -f temp.txt
cat json.xml
exit
```

But it fails

```
cp@0000 ~/work $ bash .language_file_fixer.sh before.txt
.language_file_fixer.sh: line 5: The sun is Shining: No such file or directory
cat: temp.txt: No such file or directory
.language_file_fixer.sh: line 5: The moon is dull tonight: No such file or directory
cat: temp.txt: No such file or directory
.language_file_fixer.sh: line 5: I Feel Like Dancing: No such file or directory
cat: temp.txt: No such file or directory
<message>
        <source><source>
        <translation>The sun is Shining<translation>
<message>
<message>
        <source><source>
        <translation>The moon is dull tonight<translation>
<message>
<message>
        <source><source>
        <translation>I Feel Like Dancing<translation>
<message>
```

How do I pipe the $line into sed?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to deal with this question properly. You're asking for a fix of a detail in your approach, but the approach is fundamentally flawed. You can do this all with just sed, no need for any shell looping over lines. Look at this simplified example: `sed 's/.*/<message>&<\/message>/' filename` which gets you half way there.

Comment: This Q&A is excellent to see why looping over a file is bad practice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Generating XML with `sed` has a number of inconvenient corner cases. It looks like you are trying to generate a translation resource of some sort; are you sure there isn't an existing tool for this? (Quick googling gets me http://itstool.org/documentation/ but it goes in the other direction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it completely with GNU `sed` (sed does read input file, line by line and read your instructions to process each line):

**Input:**

```
$ more messages 
The sun is Shining
The moon is dull tonight
I Feel Like Dancing
```

**Output:**

```
$ sed -n 'h;s/\(.*\)/\L\1\E/;s/ /_/g;s/\(.*\)/<message>\n\t<source>\1<\/source>/p;x;s/\(.*\)/\t<translation>\1<\/translation>\n<\/message>/p' messages 
<message>
        <source>the_sun_is_shining</source>
        <translation>The sun is Shining</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>the_moon_is_dull_tonight</source>
        <translation>The moon is dull tonight</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>i_feel_like_dancing</source>
        <translation>I Feel Like Dancing</translation>
</message>
```

**Explanations:**

For reading purpose let me split the command on several lines:

```
sed -n 'h; \
s/\(.*\)/\L\1\E/;  \
s/ /_/g; \
s/\(.*\)/<message>\n\t<source>\1<\/source>/p; \
x; \
s/\(.*\)/\t<translation>\1<\/translation>\n<\/message>/p' messages
```

- Test is done with `GNU sed 4.2.2`
- `-n` option to deactivate the autoprint mode
- `h` to save the line in the hold buffer (all the operations hereunder will be done on the pattern buffer)
- `s/\(.*\)/\L\1\E/g` is used to transform the whole line in lowercase
- `s/ /_/g` is used to transform the spaces in underscores
- `s/\(.*\)/<message>\n\t<source>\1<\/source>/p` is used to add the starting tag `<message>` followed by a line feed, a tab and `<source>` `<\/source>` surrounding the transformed message
- `p` is used to print it
- `x` is used to exchange the two buffers, after doing this operation the pattern buffer contains the line as-is
- `s/\(.*\)/\t<translation>\1<\/translation>\n<\/message>/p` is used to add the `<translation>` tags and ending `<\/message>` tag before printing the result via `p`

Comment: You should mention which sed versions that'd work in (I suspect it's GNU-only but idk) and why since it's not POSIX.

Comment: @EdMorton: Sorry I was out for lunch, I have added the explanations and I also explicitly explained that it is with GNU sed (if I remember correctly the `\L,\U,\E` operator are available only in GNU sed)

Comment: Thanks Allan. The `\n` for a newline in the replacement text is non-POSIX too (you need an escaped literal newline character for portability there). In some seds (e.g. BSD/OSX) a `\n` there will just print the letter `n`.

Comment: @Allan I saw all the edits you made. Good eye. I'm not sure if you need me to do anything but I appreciate them. Cheers.

Comment: @needtoknow: no this is fine now ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're barking up the wrong tree. This is a job for awk, not some slow, fragile, convoluted, shell loop calling sed.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    print  "<message>"
    printf "\t<source>%s</source>\n", gensub(/[[:space:]]/,"_","g",tolower($0))
    printf "\t<translation>%s</translation>\n", $0
    print "</message>"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<message>
        <source>the_sun_is_shining</source>
        <translation>The sun is Shining</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>the_moon_is_dull_tonight</source>
        <translation>The moon is dull tonight</translation>
</message>
<message>
        <source>i_feel_like_dancing</source>
        <translation>I Feel Like Dancing</translation>
</message>
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you'd use a variable and gsub().

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 'i<message>' -e 'h;y/ /_/;s/.*/\L\t<source>&<\/source>/p;x;s/.*/\t<translation>&<\/translation>/;a<\/message>' file
```

Insert a `message` tag, copy the input line, translate spaces to underscores, output the line surrounded by `source` tags and converted to lowercase. Retrieve the original line and surround by `translation` tags and append a `message` closing tag.